# How do I split one number from another to populate a field

Tags: vb.net, split, trim, truncate

I have a VendorID in the following format "24849_1". I'm trying to split the "1" off by itself and populate a field with it. The following code is what I'm using but all I'm managing to do is drop the "1" off completely. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
Dim strCustom1 As String
Dim strVendorID As String 
strCustom1 = pWorkdoc.Fields("VendorID").Text
If strCustom1 <> "" Then
   strCustom1 = Split(strCustom1, "_") (0)
   xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("RemitTo").Item(0).Text = strCustom1
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Split` but have you actually bothered to find out what it does?  It returns an array containing the split parts.  You are then getting the part at index 0 in that array.  If you actually want the part at index 1, i.e. the second part, then you should use index 1 instead of index 0.

Comment: I knew it returned an array, was just off about the index I needed. Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `Split` will give you an array, and you are taking the first element only; what you can do is:

```
strCustom1 = pWorkdoc.Fields("VendorID").Text // let it be 24849_1
If strCustom1 <> "" Then
   Dim resultArray = Split(strCustom1, "_")
   //resultArray[0] will be  24849
   //resultArray[1] will be  1
   //assign them as you need
End IF
```

Answer (score 0):

The Split function returns a String array, but you have only taken the first element (the second element which contains the "1" was discard).

Keep the split array in a variable, so that you can access both elements.

```
    Dim strCustom1 As String = "24849_1"
    Dim split As String()
    split = strCustom1.split("_")

    Console.WriteLine("Part1={0} Part2={1}", split(0), split(1))
```